# Attempt to execute non instruction

Tags: assembly, mips

This is a mips assembly code for a C code.I am simulating it using Qtspim, but I am getting an error as titled above.

```
    .text

# j=$s0 , i=$t0 

main:
        li $s0,5 # setting j to 5 
        li $t0,0 # setting i to zero


loop:
        slti $t1,$t0,8
        bne $t1,1,Exit
        add $s0,$s0,$t0
        addi $t0,$t0,1
        beq $s0,10,Exit
        j loop


Exit:
```

The C code which I am trying to convert into assembly is as below

```
  j=5;

for(t=0,i<8;i++){

    j=j+1;
    if(j==10)
        return;
}
```

Comment: How does the simulator know when to stop? Is there a 'hlt', 'brk' or similar instruction? Can you make an infinite loop at Exit: j Exit; nop; nop;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembly code seems ok. I guess your problem is that you have [*delayed branching*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot) enabled in QtSpim.
This means that the instruction that follows a branch is always executed, regardless of the action taken by the branch.

The easy fix is either to disable delayed branching, or to add a `NOP` after any branch instruction.

In your code:

```
.text
main:
        li $s0,5 # setting j to 5 
        li $t0,0 # setting i to zero


loop:
        slti $t1,$t0,8
        bne $t1,1,Exit
        nop             # added a nop to prevent the addition when branch is taken
        add $s0,$s0,$t0
        addi $t0,$t0,1
        beq $s0,10,Exit
        j loop
        nop             # added a nop to prevent executing unknown data after the unconditional jump
Exit:   
        j Exit          # code added so we don't drop off executing after this point
        nop
```

Comment: Stil the error is popping up even after editing the code as you said plus delayed branching is not enabled in qtmips settings

Comment: @Fazlan: next guess is your Exit label that has nothing after, therefore the CPU would continue executing nonsense after "exiting". I modified the snippet above to keep there after reaching Exit.

Answer (score 18):

If you are having problems with "attempt to execute non istruction at address 0x..." try adding at the end of your code this :

```
li $v0,10
syscall
```

the pc counter will always add +4 to the pc (because instructions are stored in multiplies of 4) and it will do this until you won't say EXIT FROM PROGRAM.

Yes ,the procedure of terminating the program is fault of the programmer,so you will write a exit syscall in order to terminate your code.

For who did some code in 8086 can remember that there was a .EXIT routine that return the control of the program to the DOS, so it's the same as syscall